# Google Sheets create table based on date filter on original table

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, match

Link to sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14wv2JPcefuEU-QgUB1jDK40W67ydacdzL7_2Y5xAttc/edit?usp=sharing

I have a use case where my client fills out a google sheet with the prices allowed for their products on Amazon based on either a sale period *(EOSS)* or regular period *(BAU)*. I need to create a new table based on their input table which checks today's date and determines if the EOSS price will apply or the BAU price will apply.

For example, today is 22nd November 2022. So, for the first 3 SKUs, the EOSS price will apply as today's date falls between the EOSS start date and end date. However, for the rest of the SKUs, the BAU price will apply since today's date falls outside the EOSS start date and end date.
[image]

I'm assuming that I will need to use `Query()` to solve this but I can't figure out how to get started. Google searches are not being very helpful and I would appreciate at least a suggestion on how to get this done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER({A3:C, IFERROR(A3:A/0, TEXT(TODAY(), "e-d-m")), F3:H}, 
 TODAY()>=D3:D, TODAY()<=E3:E)
```

[image]

---

### update 1:

```
={FILTER({A3:C, IFERROR(A3:A/0, TEXT(TODAY(), "e-d-m")), F3:H}, TODAY()>=D3:D, TODAY()<=E3:E); 
  FILTER({A3:C, IFERROR(A3:A/0, TEXT(TODAY(), "e-d-m")), F3:H}, ""=D3:D, ""=E3:E, ""<>A3:A)}
```

[image]

---

### update 2:

```
=SORTN({
 FILTER({A3:C, IFERROR(A3:A/0, TEXT(TODAY(), "e-d-m")), F3:H}, TODAY()>=D3:D, TODAY()<=E3:E); 
 FILTER({A3:C, IFERROR(A3:A/0, TEXT(TODAY(), "e-d-m")), F3:H}, ""=D3:D, ""=E3:E, ""<>A3:A)}, 9^9, 2, 2, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that really helps! Any idea how I can get the rest of the rows to show up too? Essentially, I need to show the BAU rows for the SKUs that are not in the EOSS period

Comment: Wow, thank you for the updated answer! Just one last ask - For the BAU rows that you added, the first 3 rows are for the SKUs that you filtered the EOSS rows for. Can you help me filter out those rows too? Essentially, from your result, I need to remove rows 4-6 as those products are showing EOSS rates

Comment: Even though it seems like magic and I'll need some time to figure out how it works, it's exactly what I need. Thank you for your help, you're amazing!